# PHP: Redirecting upon a true statement

Tags: php, mysql, html

Probably something simple I'm missing, but what I'm trying to do is finish up a registration form and after it sends a confirmation email, redirect it to another page. What I have so far

```
if($sentmail){
<redirection code>
}
else {
echo "Problem sending information, please resubmit.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), and possibly an `exit` to stop processing.

```
if ($sentmail) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/after_true_statement_redirected');
    // exit; ???
} else {
    echo "Problem sending information, please resubmit.";
}
```

Comment: Yes, as he pointed out the exit; should be included if you want the redirection to be mandatory for all types of http interaction.

Comment: Sorry, he referred to you, @Jared Farrish, about the possible commented exit.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using the [`header();`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php) function.

```
if($sentmail){
     header("Location: http://mypage.com/redirect.php");
     die();
}
else {
     echo "Problem sending information, please resubmit.";
}
```

Use `die();` to stop script execution. Though the page redirects, the script still executes.

Comment: Thanks! Surprised I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy redirect call is [`http_redirect`](http://php.net/http_redirect) in PHP. Does everything you need to do for a redirect.

```
if ($sentmail)
{    
    http_redirect('new location');
}
else
{
    echo "Problem sending information, please resubmit.";
}
```